# Plot drc using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the dose response curve using `ggplot` but when I do so it looks very different.
Is it possible to plot the curve with `ggplot` as it looks exactly when it is polotted using `plot` function from base R?

My second question about the `drm model` summary:
Which parameter is more reflective of the binding: b, c, d, or e?

```
library(drm)
library(ggplot2)

test_data <- data.frame(Conc = c(0.0004882812, 0.001953125 ,0.0078125, 0.03125 ,0.125 ,0.5),
                        Response = c(1.616017 ,1.165835, 0.5783709, 0.3440007, 0.2668585, 0.2336709))


## plot drm model
model_drm <- drm(Response ~ Conc, data=test_data,
                 fct=LL.4())
summary(model_drm)
plot(model_drm)


## now using ggplot

  ggplot(test_data, aes(x = Conc, y = Response )) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "drm",
              method.args = list(
                fct = LL.4()),se = FALSE)
```

[image]

[image]

```
Model fitted: Log-logistic (ED50 as parameter) (4 parms)

Parameter estimates:

                Estimate Std. Error t-value  p-value    
b:(Intercept) 1.15894518 0.08339821  13.896 0.005138 ** 
c:(Intercept) 0.24398009 0.01385086  17.615 0.003207 ** 
d:(Intercept) 1.81356338 0.05324814  34.059 0.000861 ***
e:(Intercept) 0.00261968 0.00020635  12.695 0.006148 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error:

 0.01758151 (2 degrees of freedom)
```

**EDIT**:
Adding the log transformation leads to that the curve is not drawn anymore:

```
ggplot(test_data, aes(x = Conc, y = Response )) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(
              method = "drm",
              method.args = list(
                fct = LL.4()
              ),
              se = FALSE
  )+
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10")
```

[image]

Comment: It looks to me as if `plot()` is using a log to the base 10 transformation on the x axis.  Try adding `+ scale_x_continuous(trans="log10")` to your `ggplot` code.

Comment: Thanks but I tried the log transformation and it removed the curve. both log2 and log10. Also when I tried to compensate that with geom_line it doesn't draw a proper curve. Only connect the points to each other.

Comment: If I replace `method="drm"` with `method="loess"` (and delete `method.args=...`) I get the expected behaviour: the line appears.  This suggests there's a problem with `method ="drm"` - which, I assume, is provided by the `drm` package.

Answer (score 1):

The X axis needs to be log10 scaled.  Also we can reuse the calculation of the model already done.

```
ggplot(cbind(test_data, fit = fitted(model_drm)), aes(x = Conc, y = Response )) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_line(aes(y = fit)) +
   scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot(test_data, aes(x = Conc, y = Response )) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = predict(model_drm))) +
  scale_x_log10()
```